# Issue passing optional parameters into C execlp()

Tags: c, command-line, optional-parameters

I'm writing a C program that uses `execlp()` to run the linux command-line tool, `convert`. This command takes optional arguments. However, when using it with `execlp()`, my C program doesn't recognize the flags I pass in and thus doesn't do the command properly.

For example, if I were to run this command in terminal `convert -resize 10% src.jpg dst.jpg` it will resize the src image by 10%, saving it to dst. However when I run my C program with this code

```
rc = execlp("convert", "-resize 10%", src, dst, NULL);
```

my computer doesn't recognize the `resize -10%` flag and doesn't do anything to my source image. Why is that?

Comment: `"-resize 10%"` is two args. Pass them seperately.

Comment: Most likely, the `-resize` should be one option and `10%` should be another.  Using `execlp()` is a bad idea if you have variable numbers of arguments — use `execvp()` instead, building an array of arguments terminated by a null pointer.  Use `execlp()` only when the argument list is fixed.

Comment: @kaylum still doesn't work, it registers the "10%" as the image file unfortunately

Comment: What do you type on the command line to execute the resize operation?  That will be a strong indication of what you need in the `execlp()` command.  Do you need `-resize=10%`?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler no just `-resize 10%` works

Comment: You don't type: `-resize 10%` as the command line: you type something like `convert -resize 10% source target`.  So, in the `execlp()`, you need `execlp("convert", "convert", "-resize", "10%", "source", "target", (char *)0);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By convention, the first parameter to a process (accessible as `argv[0]`) is the name of the process.  You haven't included that, so `"-resize 10%"` is read as the process name instead of an option.

Also, `"-resize 10%"` is actually two parameters separated by a space, so you need to split them up.

```
rc = execlp("convert", "convert", "-resize", "10%", src, dst, NULL);
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, the `-resize` should be one option and `10%` should be another:

```
rc = execlp("convert", "convert", "-resize", "10%", src, dst, NULL);
```

Using `execlp()` is a bad idea if you have variable numbers of arguments — use `execvp()` instead, building an array of arguments terminated by a null pointer.  Use `execlp()` only when the argument list is fixed.

```
char *args[6];
int i = 0;
args[i++] = "convert";
args[i++] = "-resize";
args[i++] = "10%";
args[i++] = src;
args[i++] = dst;
args[i++] = NULL;

rc = execvp(args[0], args);
```

Note that this formula ensures that the program name is passed correctly — once as a string that is searched for on `$PATH`, and once as the `argv[0]` of the executed program.

With `execlp()`, as [dbush](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1687119/dbush) [notes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70661003/15168), you have to repeat the command name — once to specify the executable and once to specify the value for `argv[0]`.

Note too that there is nothing to stop you from telling the program via `argv[0]` that it has a wholly different name from the name that you execute.  This rarely happens (shells don't do it) but when you write the code yourself, it is possible.